# Android studio - Create and share pdf

Tags: android, android-layout, pdf, bitmap, share

actually I try to create and share a pdf based on my activity.

This is my java code:

```
    public class Masskonfigurator_Zeichnung extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv_Ps_Mass;
    private TextView tv_C_Mass;
    private TextView tv_A_Mass;
    private TextView tv_B_Mass;
    private TextView tv_H1_Mass;
    private TextView tv_TBB_Mass;
    private TextView tv_TBH_Mass;
    private TextView tv_H2_Mass;
    private TextView tv_Zs;
    private TextView tv_FWST;
    private TextView tv_Im;
    private FloatingActionButton fabShare;
    private FrameLayout frameView;
    private boolean aBoolean;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_masskonfigurator_zeichnung);


        fabShare = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabshare);
        frameView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameview);
        GestureFrameLayout gfl = (GestureFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.gfv);


        gfl.getController().getSettings()
                .setMaxZoom(2f)
                .setDoubleTapZoom(-1f)
                .setPanEnabled(true)
                .setZoomEnabled(true)
                .setDoubleTapEnabled(true)
                .setOverscrollDistance(0f,0f)
                .setOverzoomFactor(2f)
                .setFillViewport(false)
                .setFitMethod(Settings.Fit.INSIDE)
                .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


        String tv_ps_Mass = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt0");
        TextView tv_Ps_Mass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ps_mass);
        tv_Ps_Mass.setText(tv_ps_Mass);

        String tv_c_Mass = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt1");
        TextView tv_C_Mass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_c_mass);
        tv_C_Mass.setText(tv_c_Mass);

        String tv_a_Mass = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt2");
        TextView tv_A_Mass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_a_mass);
        tv_A_Mass.setText(tv_a_Mass);

        String tv_b_Mass = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt3");
        TextView tv_B_Mass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_b_mass);
        tv_B_Mass.setText(tv_b_Mass);

        String tv_h1_Mass = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt4");
        TextView tv_H1_Mass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_h1_mass);
        tv_H1_Mass.setText(tv_h1_Mass);

        String tv_tbb_Mass = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt5");
        TextView tv_TBB_Mass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_tbb_mass);
        tv_TBB_Mass.setText(tv_tbb_Mass);

        String tv_tbh_Mass = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt6");
        TextView tv_TBH_Mass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_tbh_mass);
        tv_TBH_Mass.setText(tv_tbh_Mass);

        String tv_h2_Mass = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt7");
        TextView tv_H2_Mass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_h2_mass);
        tv_H2_Mass.setText(tv_h2_Mass);

        String tv_zs = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt8");
        TextView tv_Zs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_zs);
        tv_Zs.setText(tv_zs);

        String tv_fwst = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt9");
        TextView tv_Fwst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fwst);
        tv_Fwst.setText(tv_fwst);

        String tv_im = getIntent().getStringExtra("txt10");
        TextView tv_Im = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_im);
        tv_Im.setText(tv_im);

        ImageView iv_Techn_Zeichnung = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_techn_zeichnung);
        int iv1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("iv1", 0);
        iv_Techn_Zeichnung.setImageResource(iv1);

        if (checkPermission()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            requestPermission();
        }

        fabShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("size", "" + frameView.getWidth() + " " + frameView.getWidth());
                bitmap = LoadBitmap(frameView, frameView.getWidth(), frameView.getHeight());
                createPdf();

            }
        });
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int permission1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int permission2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return permission1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permission2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private Bitmap LoadBitmap(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        v.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;

}

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void createPdf() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
          Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHighet, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, convertWidth, convertHighet, true);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        document.finishPage(page);

        // write the document content
//        String targetPdf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Drawing";
//        File file;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "Drawing.pdf");
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }////////////////////

        // close the document
        document.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "successfully pdf created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//        share();
        openPdf();

    }

    private void openPdf() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Drawing.pdf");

        if (file.exists()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Masskonfigurator_Zeichnung.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Application for pdf view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

And thats my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<com.alexvasilkov.gestures.views.GestureFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gfv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Deutschland.Masskonfigurator_Zeichnung">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootview">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_techn_zeichnung"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/unico_ef_mw_htb_fwst145_270" />

    //C-Maß Guidelines
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.94"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="4dp" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_c_mass"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="C"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.225"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.384"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"/>

    
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabshare"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.145"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.975"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            app:fabSize="auto"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp" />





</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>


</com.alexvasilkov.gestures.views.GestureFrameLayout>
```

It seems to work. I can choose an App for viewing the pdf file but then I get the error toast: Couldn´t access to this file. Please check the length of the filename or your connection.

I think, there is only still a little problem with my path, in which I save the pdf file.

EDIT:
Improved the code. Hopefully almost done.

May there is someone who can help me, pleeeeaase :-)

Thanks and have a nice day,
Daniel

Comment: It makes no sense to post a hundred of TextView's. Please minimize your code. If you tell that you have a pdf file we will believe you. Or cant you create a pdf file? Its pretty unclear where you have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. It's not necessary to read the wwhole xml file. I just wanted to show all files. I also can delete it from my question. I want to create and share a pdf of my activity by clicking on the fab.

Comment: I found small but important Beginner mistake, now :-D On my device, I didn't allow the app the access to my storage. I changed it and now I get a white screen for longer time and then it cancels and go back to previous activity. Today evening I will chck the logcat...